# Content Query fails

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

Could you please look at my CQ. I modified `ViewFieldsOverride`, `ListsOverride`. Only the Lists works, the `ViewFieldsOverride` makes it

> There is a problem with the query that this Web Part is issuing. Check
>   the configuration of this Web Part and try again

```
   <webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Filter1ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
        <property name="FilterOperator1" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
        <property name="FilterOperator3" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="GroupByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
        <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
        <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
        <property name="SystemViewFields" type="string" />
        <property name="ListName" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterDisplayValue3" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterDisplayValue2" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterDisplayValue1" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterField1" type="string" />
        <property name="Description" type="string">Displays a dynamic view of content from your site.</property>
        <property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string" />
        <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
        <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
        <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string" />
        <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string" />
        <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="AdditionalFilterFields" type="string" />
        <property name="DataMappingViewFields" type="string">{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},Lookup;{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},Image;{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Text;{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},Text;</property>
        <property name="Title" type="string">All projects6</property>
        <property name="FeedDescription" type="string" />
        <property name="UseCache" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="XslLink" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="AutoRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Filter1IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="FilterValue3" type="string" />
        <property name="SortByFieldType" type="string">DateTime</property>
        <property name="ManualRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
        <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ItemStyle" type="string">Default</property>
        <property name="SampleData" type="string">&lt;dsQueryResponse&gt;
                    &lt;Rows&gt;
                        &lt;Row Title="Item 1" LinkUrl="http://Item1" Group="Group Header" __begincolumn="True" __begingroup="True" /&gt;
                        &lt;Row Title="Item 2" LinkUrl="http://Item2" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;
                        &lt;Row Title="Item 3" LinkUrl="http://Item3" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;
                    &lt;/Rows&gt;
                    &lt;/dsQueryResponse&gt;</property>
        <property name="FilterIncludeChildren2" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="XmlDefinitionLink" type="string" />
        <property name="ServerTemplate" type="string">4501</property>
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string" />
        <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
        <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
        <property name="ListGuid" type="string" />
        <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
        <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="GroupByFieldType" type="string" />
        <property name="Default" type="string" />
        <property name="ViewFlags" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewFlags, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">None</property>
        <property name="ContentTypeBeginsWithId" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="FeedEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="SortBy" type="string">{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}</property>
        <property name="FilterByContextTerm" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="PlayMediaInBrowser" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ViewFlag" type="string">0</property>
        <property name="Xsl" type="string">&lt;xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cmswrt x" &gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl" /&gt; &lt;/xsl:stylesheet&gt;</property>
        <property name="FilterField2" type="string" />
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
        <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
        <property name="AdditionalGroupAndSortFields" type="string" />
        <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Height" type="string" />
        <property name="DataMappings" type="string">Description:{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},ShortComment,Text;|ImageUrl:{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|LinkUrl:{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},FileRef,Lookup;|</property>
        <property name="ListUrl" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="ShowUntargetedItems" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="GroupBy" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterIncludeChildren1" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="BaseType" type="string" />
        <property name="MainXslLink" type="string" />
        <property name="AsyncRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="FilterValue1" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterValue2" type="string" />
        <property name="InitialAsyncDataFetch" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="AutoRefreshInterval" type="int">60</property>
        <property name="Filter3IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="GroupStyle" type="string">DefaultHeader</property>
        <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="FilterIncludeChildren3" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="EnableOriginalValue" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ItemLimit" type="int">15</property>
        <property name="FilterType1" type="string" />
        <property name="UseCopyUtil" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="FilterType3" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterType2" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterOperator2" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="PageType" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">PAGE_NORMALVIEW</property>
        <property name="FilterByAudience" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ItemXslLink" type="string" />
        <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="WebUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="HeaderXslLink" type="string" />
        <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ListsOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<Lists><List ID="1D0E7508-4607-4AAF-A5E9-90ADE1E84784"/><List ID="6A279AD6-A9B8-438B-8400-292A44618BF8"/></Lists> ]]></property>
        <property name="SortByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
        <property name="Filter2IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="FeedTitle" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterField3" type="string" />
        <property name="MediaPlayerStyleSource" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="DisplayColumns" type="int">1</property>
        <property name="Filter2ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
        <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string" />
        <property name="WebsOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ContentTypeName" type="string" />
        <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" />
        <property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[
            <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="Text"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Description" Type="Note"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Estimated_x0020_hours" Type="Number"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Hours_x0020_spent" Type="Number"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Author" Type="User" />
            <ListProperty Name="Title" />
            <ProjectProperty Name="Title" />
        ]]></property>
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="ListDisplayName" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="Width" type="string" />
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the whitespace from your ViewFieldsOverride property, it should be all on one line.  The following code block is taken from the SPSiteDataQuery (which is used internally to retrieve the data) during XML validation:

```
            try
            {
                while (SPSiteDataQuery.ReadRootXmlElement(xmlReader))
                {
                    if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && (strTag == null || !(xmlReader.Name != strTag) || strTag2 != null && !(xmlReader.Name != strTag2) || strTag3 != null && !(xmlReader.Name != strTag3)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    SPSiteDataQuery.ReportInvalidProperty(null, strPropertyName);
                }
            }
            catch (XmlException xmlException)
            {
                SPSiteDataQuery.ReportInvalidProperty(xmlException, strPropertyName);
            }
```

You can see from the above, that if the XmlReader hits a newline it returns a whitespace NodeType and the method throws an exception.

Good luck.